# Word to describe both adding and removing but not updating

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I am looking for a word that can describe the act of adding/removing objects but at the same time avoid a word that has to do with updating.

So, given

1. adding an object,
2. removing an object,
3. updating an object,

I want a word for ((1 *and* 2) *and not* 3). So I guess words like *alter* won't do.

**Edit:** I am actually making an application, and I have three methods; adding, removing and updating. But there is some logic in both the adding and removing that is common. I then decided to make a fourth (helper) method. That's why I need this word so badly.

Comment: So you're asking whether there is a word that means both to add something *and* to remove it? A word that means its opposite?

Comment: Yes. It may sound silly, but I was hoping there was a "common denominator".

Comment: _Reconfigure_, maybe? More context would help.

Comment: @ Callithumpian: Done.

Comment: If you add or remove an object / objects to/from a set/list, _by definition_ you're updating / changing that set/list.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes" is specifically off-topic for this site. That goes for functions and methods as well.

Comment: You might want to ask on StackOverflow, since this must come up for CRUD operations. I guess that adding and deleting are parts of the *lifecycle* of the objects, and you could argue that modifying is not. It wouldn't be clear to me as a dev. If this is just for some common functions, you could use AddDeleteCommon (adapted to whatever case consistency pattern you use). Don't sacrifice clarity for DRYness. You could include the common functions for modify as well, and just not use any.

Comment: Ifit's code, just make it self documenting by being explicit, a few saved charcters is not worth confusion. container.Add(object), container.Remove(object), and container.AddRemove(object, bool = add)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class containing a collection of immutable objects might be a ***stack***, where you *push* items in and *pop* them out.  But if `PushPop()` doesn't do it for you, how about something like ***shift***, with the implication that you can shift items onto or off of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

If this is about method naming, then you really don't need a bona fide English word. You can construct your own hybrid. The obvious one that comes off the top of my head is

```
addOrRemoveObject()
```

but you should feel free to use whatever fits with your naming convention.

Comment: It's possible. However, I was hoping to avoid this approach.

Answer (score 0):

What about **to substitute**?

According to the OALD, it means "*to take the place of somebody/something else; to use somebody/something instead of somebody/something else*".

Or also **to replace**, "*to be used instead of something/somebody else; to do something instead of somebody/something else*".

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding, removing, and altering objects in a list, are you not "editing" that list?

Answer (score 0):

I do not really have an answer, but I have a suggestion that might help to find your answer in a different way.

You are talking about adding, removing, and updating objects, so you are presumably building some kind of container, and the objects are the items in the container.

When you are thinking at the level of the items, it is hard to come up with a term that can mean either addition or removal of an individual item.

However, if you shift your thinking to the level of the container, then either the addition or the removal of an item is ***a modification of the container***. (Whereas direct modification to an existing item does not affect the container.). So, instead of `itemAdditionOrDeletion` you could perhaps use something along the lines of `containerModification`.

Answer (score 0):

While Shift should work to any programing that learned programming, if you have some modern pure UX people far closer to graphic designers than programmers - while they still ~should~ know shift it might all be a bit hazy for them

Helper methods are not far from a "markup" kinda thing - they'd never read the helper, just use it like [B] for bold [/B] but more like [ if( HelpyShiftyName) "<p {color = green, style=bold }" else "<p {style=bold >" ]

So I would suggest not Shift but maybe "ListObject?" or "IncludeObject" - but that isn't plain english "Included-object" fits more english compound word rules?

Answer (score -5):

I believe the term you're looking for is "Absolute Value".  If you add $40K and delete $20K, then your absolute value is $60K.